# Libraries collision in iOS, React Native and AWS Iot

Tags: ios, react-native, collision, aws-iot

I am trying to developing an iOS App with React Native and with AWSIoT library. (AWSIoT library include in other pod for iOS)
When I am trying to run this project, the build is failed duo to 12 duplicate codes in classes For example:
❌ duplicate symbol 'OBJC_IVAR$_SRIOConsumer._unmaskBytes' in ┌─ libAWSIoT.a(AWSSRWebSocket.o) └─ libSocketRocket.a(SRIOConsumer.o)

AWSSRWebSocket include @interface SRIOConsumer and SocketRocket (from ReactNative) also has the same @interface SRIOConsumer .
Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue?

I tried to rename SRIOConsumer in AWS to AWSSRIOConsumer.
The code compiled but the app crashed with SIGABORD.

I cant move the AWS library to react native code because it in iOS native library